# created gif does not show up completely in php with gifcreator lib

Tags: php, html, image, gif, gd

I have a problem, my company wants refreshing timers in email marketing, so I watched up and found a good explanation with a tutorial on how to do that. So I followed along and everything works great, also the gif is saved correctly. But as I said I need that in a Mailing so it should already echo out the gif content. There begins the struggle, instead of showing up the whole gif it's only creating a half frame of each.

## **Resources**

- Gitcreator lib https://github.com/Sybio/GifCreator
- PHP 8.0
- [Tutorial ->](https://dev.to/grahamthedev/this-gif-is-accurate-to-within-a-minute-how-to-create-a-dynamic-gif-countdown-3fhd)

## **Code**#

My Code for how to handle it would be like that...

```
namespace GifMake;
use \GifCreator;
use \Datetime;

include 'Gif.class.php';
include 'GifCreator/src/GifCreator/GifCreator.php';

$now = new DateTime();
$ends = new DateTime('Nov 15, 2022, 08:00:00');
$left = $now->diff($ends);

$days = $left->format('%a');
$hours = $left->format('%h');
$minutes = $left->format('%i');
$seconds = $left->format('%s');


for ($x = 0; $x < 60; $x++) {

    if ($seconds < 0) {
        $seconds = 59;
        $minutes--;
    }
    if ($minutes < 0) {
        $minutes = 59;
        $hours--;
    }
    if ($hours < 0) {
        $hours = 23;
        $days--;
    }

    if ($now < $ends) {

        $img = new gifMake;
        $img->texts[] = array(26, 0, 38, 100, "#333333", "arial.ttf", "InHu Launches in...");
        // we use str_pad to make sure our days, minutes etc. have at least 2 figures
        $img->texts[] = array(26, 0, 80, 150, "#333333", "arial.ttf", str_pad($days, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
        $img->texts[] = array(26, 0, 213, 150, "#763289", "arial.ttf", "Days");
        $img->texts[] = array(26, 0, 80, 190, "#333333", "arial.ttf", str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
        $img->texts[] = array(26, 0, 197, 190, "#763289", "arial.ttf", "Hours");
        $img->texts[] = array(26, 0, 80, 230, "#333333", "arial.ttf", str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
        $img->texts[] = array(26, 0, 169, 230, "#763289", "arial.ttf", "Minutes");
        $img->texts[] = array(26, 0, 80, 270, "#333333", "arial.ttf", str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
        $img->texts[] = array(26, 0, 150, 270, "#763289", "arial.ttf", "Seconds");

        $img->createImg();
        $fileName = "./img/sequence/img" . $x;
        $img->saveAsPng($fileName);

    }
    $seconds --;
}

$frames = array();
for($x = 0; $x < 60; $x++){
    $frames[] = "img/sequence/img" . $x . ".png";
    $durations[] = 100;
}
$gc = new GifCreator\GifCreator();
$gc->create($frames, $durations, 10);
$gifBinary = $gc->getGif();
file_put_contents("img/countdown.gif", $gifBinary);

header('Content-Type: image/gif');

$f = file_get_contents('img/countdown.gif');

echo $gifBinary;
```

and the class for the make off for the gif...

```
<?php

namespace GifMake;

class gifMake
{

    public array $texts = array();
    private \GdImage $image;

    function hexToRGB($colour): bool|array
    {
        if ($colour[0] == '#') {
            $colour = substr($colour, 1);
        }
        if (strlen($colour) == 6) {
            list($r, $g, $b) = array($colour[0] . $colour[1], $colour[2] . $colour[3], $colour[4] . $colour[5]);
        } elseif (strlen($colour) == 3) {
            list($r, $g, $b) = array($colour[0] . $colour[0], $colour[1] . $colour[1], $colour[2] . $colour[2]);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        $r = hexdec($r);
        $g = hexdec($g);
        $b = hexdec($b);
        return array('r' => $r, 'g' => $g, 'b' => $b);
    }

    function createImg(): bool
    {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('inhu-countdown-lrg.jpg');

        foreach ($this->texts as $item) {

            $fontSize = $item[0];
            $angle = $item[1];
            $x = $item[2];
            $y = $item[3];
            $textColourHex = $item[4];
            $fontFamily = $item[5];
            $text = $item[6];

            $textColourRGB = $this->hexToRGB($textColourHex);
            $textColourImg = imagecolorallocate(
                $image,
                $textColourRGB['r'],
                $textColourRGB['g'],
                $textColourRGB['b']);

            imagettftext($image,
                $fontSize,
                $angle,
                $x,
                $y,
                $textColourImg,
                $fontFamily,
                $text);
        }

        $this->image = $image;
        return true;
    }

    function saveAsPng($fileName = 'text-image', $location = ''): bool
    {
        $fileName = $fileName . ".png";
        $fileName = !empty($location) ? $location : $fileName;
        return imagepng($this->image, $fileName);
    }

    function saveAsJpg($fileName = 'text-image', $location = ''): bool
    {
        $fileName = $fileName . ".jpg";
        $fileName = !empty($location) ? $location . $fileName : $fileName;
        return imagejpeg($this->image, $fileName);
    }

    function showImage(): bool
    {
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        return imagepng($this->image);
    }

}
```

If somebody knows where the problem is coming from, I would appreciate any tips and what to do!!

I already tried to make it via an short sleep before echo out the gif content, would expect that the gif is showing up properly without fails.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you mean by _"a half frame of each"_?

Comment: Hey yeah sure, it looks like this https://iili.io/H9JJZmB.jpg ... And that is like for the whole gif sequence

Comment: I'm a bit surprised it works at all. From what I can see the frames in `create($frames, $durations, 10)` have to be of the type `GdImage`, whereas you use paths.

Comment: the lib converts images as files into GDImage type ... if you watch inside the lib source code from row 106 - 118.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that explains it.